# Anaconda TensorFlow Installation Error "HTTP"How to fix?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, spyder, self-signed

I was trying to install Tensorflow by creating an environment but I got an error because I my Self-Signed Certificate. I fixed this once with pip but I don't know how to do that with Anaconda.

The error is:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.

SSLError(MaxRetryError('HTTPSConnectionPool(host=\'repo.anaconda.com\', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([(\'SSL routines\', \'tls_process_server_certificate\', \'certificate verify failed\')])")))'))
```

I tried to find a command to fix that but could not find one. I am supposed to be able to create the environment without any issue.

Comment: Could you please share how exactly you have tried to install Tensorflow in Anaconda? I have installed it, but didn't have any problem.

Comment: conda create -n tensorflow_demo python=3.5
I used that to create an environment. I have not installed Tensorflow yet.

Comment: Try to do it without environment and also check default Python version on Anaconda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have searched on Internet and found something related to Conda issue. 
Before going to 1) and 2) steps, just type

`conda config --set ssl_verify no`

Then do following:

1. Create new environment by typing(optional)

   `conda create -n tensorflow pip python=3.7
   activate tensorflow`
2. Install Tensorflow 1.9

   `pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow==1.9`

I didn't get any error with this. If you have errors, comment down below.

Comment: When I tried to create the environment (#1) I got this error:
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.

Comment: HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.

SSLError(MaxRetryError('HTTPSConnectionPool(host=\'repo.anaconda.com\', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([(\'SSL routines\', \'tls_process_server_certificate\', \'certificate verify failed\')])")))'))

Comment: Do I use the pip command in the Anaconda Prompt or Command Prompt?
Also, is it okay if I install TensorFlow 2.0 instead?

Comment: Before doing 1) and 2) parts, just type `conda config --set ssl_verify no` in Anaconda prompt. Then try to do 1) and 2) parts.

Comment: Check my other question above!

Comment: If you are still getting errors, please edit your question and let us know what error you are getting.